# Is it possible to cache in AWS API Gateway using request body as cache key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql

I have an AWS API Gateway that sits in front of a GraphQL Lambda function. I am looking to implement caching to improve the performance of my API.

After some research, I came across a suggestion to use the integration request in API Gateway to calculate a hash from the request body and pass it as a custom header. This custom header could then be used as a cache key to cache the responses based on the unique request body.

However, I'm not entirely sure about the implementation details and whether this approach would work correctly with my existing GraphQL Lambda setup. I want to ensure that the GraphQL Lambda function still receives the original request body.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this? Specifically, I would like to know:

1. How can I configure the API Gateway integration request to calculate the hash from the request body and pass it as a custom header?
2. Is it possible to enable caching for POST Method in combination with that setup?
3. Are there any potential issues or considerations I should be aware of when using this approach with GraphQL or AWS Lambda?

Any help or code examples demonstrating how to set up the integration request and handle the caching with API Gateway and GraphQL Lambda would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If GraphQL is serving authenticated users then the request body may not be enough to uniquely identify the results you want, you might need  to include the user's ID as a key as well (often provided via a header via a JWT)

Comment: That's a good point, but this particular API is not serving authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

[image]1- You doesn't need to calculate anything on your integration. All caching logic is encapsulated on ApiGW, you just need to set up it.

2- Setup caching on POST method is dangerous but you can do it.

3- AWS recommend that you run 10 minutes load test,so you can detect any possible issue.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#override-api-gateway-stage-cache-for-method-cache

Comment: Do you see any reference in the documentation or do you see on AWS console level option for using the request body as a cache key?

Comment: I see it on AWS console, you have to enable caching at the stage-level and override caching setup at the method-level

Comment: I, unfortunately, fail to see any mention of the request body on either resource/stage tab on the API Gateway, in the context of caching..